# Check if row is deleted or not

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm currently developing on cassandra source (2.0.4) and I am wondering how the method isMarkedForDelete() in the class ColumnFamily is used. If I insert a row with a key, the method returns false, if I delete the row, it returns true. That´s the way I expect it ;-) But, and that's the point I'm wondering about, if I insert a row with the same key again, the method still returns false, although the row is not deleted (since it is a new row with the same key). It seems that a deleted and reinserted row always keeps the flag if it was deleted once in the past. How can I reliably determine if a row is deleted or not?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

A delete is Cassandra is accomplished by writing a new row known as a tombstone.  The tombstone will ensure that the row is not returned in any queries (one the tombstone has reached full consistency on all nodes).

The row is actually removed from the SSTables when the following are satisfied:

1. Compaction occurs
2. The tombstone record is older than gc_grace_seconds for the table (default is 10 days)

Inserting a row with a key that already exists will not cause an error since the data structure in Cassandra behaves much like a Java Map.  "putting" a rows with the same key will just overwrite the column values from your insert, and succeed.

The best way to determine if the row has been delete is to query for the row and ensure it is not returned in the query.

I'm not sure which client you are using, but with C* 2.0 you should use the DataStax Java Driver (current release is 2.0.2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand the principle of tombstones to mark a row for delete which is done later on a compact. But why is the tombstone not removed if a row is reinserted with the same key before the row is actually removed from the SSTables?

Comment: If you insert the row again after you deleted it, the tombstone for that row key is no longer the most recent "write" for that rowkey, so at that point the tombstone is irrelevant.